# Adding attachment to EWS email (using VBA)

Tags: excel, xml, vba, soap, exchangewebservices

**Second update**

I wasn't paying a lot of attention when I was coding, as I put the "/" in the wrong spot in `</t:ContentLocation>`, etc. That's figured out for now.

Though I still can't get it working properly as I'm getting the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="15" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="2242" MinorBuildNumber="10" Version="V2017_07_11" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><m:CreateItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><m:ResponseMessages><m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error"><m:MessageText>Required property is missing.</m:MessageText><m:ResponseCode>ErrorRequiredPropertyMissing</m:ResponseCode><m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey><m:MessageXml><t:ExceptionFieldURI FieldURI="attachment:Name"/></m:MessageXml><m:Items/></m:CreateItemResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:CreateItemResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

So apparently the attachment name gives an error. When I add

`sReq = sReq & "<t:Name>" & "testdoc.pdf" & "</t:Name>" & vbCrLf`

it produces a the same error on `t:ExceptionFieldURI FieldURI="attachment:Content"`

- Am I doing the absolute URI wrong? How do I state a local file and
  how do I state a file from a https source (Sharepoint)?
- Are there required parts that I'm missing?

---

I’m trying to send an email through EWS which works perfectly. Though when I try adding a file (local) attachment, I get a 500 http status. Does anyone know what I’m missing?

```
Dim sReq As String
Dim xmlMethod As String
Dim XMLreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim EWSEndPoint As String:     EWSEndPoint = "SERVER ADDRESS”

sReq = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:t=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"">" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2016""/>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</soap:Header>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<CreateItem MessageDisposition=""SendAndSaveCopy"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"">" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=""sentitems"" />" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<Items>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:Message>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:Subject>" & "SUBJECT" & "</t:Subject>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:Body BodyType=""Text"">" & "TEXT" & "</t:Body>" & vbCrLf

   sReq = sReq & "<t:Attachments>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:FileAttachment>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:ContentLocation>" & "file://H:/testdoc.pdf"  & "<t:/ContentLocation>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:/FileAttachment>" & vbCrLf
   sReq = sReq & "<t:/Attachments>" & vbCrLf

sReq = sReq & "<t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "<t:EmailAddress>" & "email@something.com" & "</t:EmailAddress>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</t:Message>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</Items>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</CreateItem>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</soap:Body>" & vbCrLf
sReq = sReq & "</soap:Envelope>" & vbCrLf
 
xmlMethod = "POST"
XMLreq.Open xmlMethod, EWSEndPoint, False, "user", "pass"
XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
XMLreq.Send sReq
```

**Update:**

By using `XMLreq.responseText` in my code, I got the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="nl-NL">The request failed schema validation: Name cannot begin with the '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F. Line 1, position 339.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message><t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:LineNumber>0</t:LineNumber><t:LinePosition>0</t:LinePosition><t:Violation>Name cannot begin with the '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F. Line 1, position 339.</t:Violation></t:MessageXml></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Can anyone explain what’s going wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange includes how to manage attachments.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim. I'm aware of those contents and I'm pretty sure I followed all instructions stated there. Still not getting it to work though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is from almost one year ago, but ... just saw it now by looking for solution to same problem in VBA.
The article mentioned by Tim Williams shows clearly, that you have to use the MimeContent (which is Base64 encoded ASCII string) of your to-be-attached file, not the file itself!

My working solution:

1. First create a Base64 encoded string of your file content by creating a function which uses the ADODB.Stream object to read the file content bytewise into a string and then use the MSXML2.DOMDocumentxx library to encode the string to Base64 string, then
2. use the "/t:Content" tag instead of "t:/ContentLocation":

`sReq = sReq & "<t:Content>" & yourBase64String & "</t:Content>" & vbCrLf`

Apart from that, you had a typo in your post: "<t:/ContentLocation>" is wrong - must be "</t:ContentLocation>"